# Axios отправляет пустой объект на Flask сервер

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, axios

Моя функция отправки запроса

```
type CategoryT = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  creation_date: string;
  creator_id: number;
};

 async function PostNewCategory(category: CategoryT): Promise<void> {
  Axios.post("/addCategory", category).then(
    (response) => {
      if (response.data != null) {
        alert("Category was posted successfully");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Функция Flask

```
@main.route('/addCategory', methods=['POST'])
def add_category():
    category_data = request.get_json()
    now = datetime.now()

    new_category = Category(
        name=category_data['name'],
        creationDate=now,
        creator_id=category_data['creator_id'])

    db.session.add(new_category)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Done', 201
```

Если отправлять json с константами, например

```
{
"name" : "some name",
"creator_id": "123"
}
```

то сервер принимает эти данные.
Не могу понять, в чем проблема.
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: что такое CategoryT, его точно можно отправить?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, да, добавил CategoryT в вопрос.

Comment: а что средства-разработчика-в -браузере говорят, идет json в теле?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, если обернуть category  в фигурные скобки, отправляется такой объект:  {category: "some category"}. Если не оборачивать, получаю some category:

Comment: а в дебагере брейкпоинт поставить и поставить и посмотреть, что в `category` можно? или `console.log(category.id)`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, точно! Я передаю строку вместо CategoryT. Спасибо!! Буду исправлять

Comment: Наздоровье. Пользуйтесь инструментами отладки. Они для фронта хорошие.